# How Can I precompress files Using Xtool?

Tags: windows

How Can I precompress files using Xtool by Razor12911.
Files [here](https://archive.org/download/xtool_0.3.21.7z/xtool_0.3.21.7z)

My pc

1.Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10400 CPU @ 2.90GHz 2.90 GHz

2.8gb ram

What's the best compression ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "**srep+lolz**" to compress it. Or use a custom Compressor like mini compressor and DiskSpan

Comment: Still cant understand. Can you tell from starting ?